# how do you stop an object from blender that was attached to a rig (also from blender) into unity from deforming?

Tags: rigging, import, unity

[image: this is what it should look like normally]I have created a hand like object that was attached to a rig parented to a monkey like thing. I created this all in blender but when I imported this all into unity, If I move the hand it deforms a lot. I would really appreciate an answer because I am creating a game on a deadline. thanks

[image: this is what it looks like deformed. its very subtle but its really annoying to anyone looking at it.]